# UIImagePickerController's pushViewController misplace pushed view behind the navigation bar

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

When I push a view controller into UIImagePickerController object, the view controller's view is misplaced behind the navigation bar. no matter what I choose as image picker source. I present image picker modally and do the following in its delegate

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
  [picker setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

  SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
  [picker pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
  [secondVC release];
}
```

and in SecondViewController's doing nothing special.

When I pushed the same view controller into UINavigationController's object, it is placed correctly beneath the navigation bar.
What should I do additionally to use image picker as navigation controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have set image picker's navigation bar's [translucent](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/translucent) property NO before push second view controller.

Comment: This helped! Do you know why?