# UIImagePickerController, PushView controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios6.0

[image]I am able to Push a newview controller in below Method on iOS 7, while same code doesn't work on iOS 6. On iOS 6 it pushes view but Navigation bar show below the status bar. View look so Ugly. Can some one have any idea.  Thanks

Already checked :

[UIImagePickerController's pushViewController misplace pushed view behind the navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201042/uiimagepickercontrollers-pushviewcontroller-misplace-pushed-view-behind-the-nav)

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
         didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                   editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    AddEffectViewController *addEffectViewController=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddEffectViewController"];
    addEffectViewController.originalImage=image;

    picker.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = true;
    [picker setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [picker pushViewController:addEffectViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same as you building my photo editor, and doing this resolved it for me:

In your AddEffectViewController:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide your navigation bar

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```